# group lines based on distance between them

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list of dictionaries, where each dict represents a line. What would be a nice way of grouping the lines based on the distance between y1 coordinates?

```
horizontal_lines = [
    {'x1': 2257, 'y1': 2787, 'x2': 2419, 'y2': 2787},
    {'x1': 2256, 'y1': 2788, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2788},
    {'x1': 2256, 'y1': 2789, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2789},
    {'x1': 2256, 'y1': 2790, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2790},
    {'x1': 2256, 'y1': 2791, 'x2': 2459, 'y2': 2798},
    {'x1': 2265, 'y1': 2791, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2791},
    {'x1': 2409, 'y1': 2792, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2796},
    {'x1': 2351, 'y1': 2792, 'x2': 2454, 'y2': 2794},
    {'x1': 2352, 'y1': 2794, 'x2': 2431, 'y2': 2794},
    {'x1': 2317, 'y1': 2795, 'x2': 2431, 'y2': 2798},
    {'x1': 2255, 'y1': 2795, 'x2': 2316, 'y2': 2795},
    {'x1': 2255, 'y1': 2796, 'x2': 2316, 'y2': 2797},
    {'x1': 2339, 'y1': 2797, 'x2': 2395, 'y2': 2798},

    {'x1': 1892, 'y1': 125, 'x2': 2124, 'y2': 125},
    {'x1': 2127, 'y1': 126, 'x2': 2200, 'y2': 127},
    {'x1': 1981, 'y1': 126, 'x2': 2126, 'y2': 126},
    {'x1': 2004, 'y1': 127, 'x2': 2183, 'y2': 127},
    {'x1': 2116, 'y1': 128, 'x2': 2350, 'y2': 128},
    {'x1': 2439, 'y1': 129, 'x2': 2648, 'y2': 129},
    {'x1': 2285, 'y1': 130, 'x2': 2395, 'y2': 131},
    {'x1': 2339, 'y1': 130, 'x2': 2761, 'y2': 130},
    {'x1': 2396, 'y1': 131, 'x2': 2801, 'y2': 131},
    {'x1': 3003, 'y1': 132, 'x2': 3137, 'y2': 132},
    {'x1': 2567, 'y1': 132, 'x2': 2842, 'y2': 132},
    {'x1': 2969, 'y1': 133, 'x2': 3138, 'y2': 133},
    {'x1': 2607, 'y1': 133, 'x2': 2842, 'y2': 133},
    {'x1': 2915, 'y1': 134, 'x2': 3208, 'y2': 134},
]
```

I would like to group all elements with distance y1 10 or less together. In this case that means the first 13 lines and the last 14 lines will be grouped.

desired result:

```
groups = [
    [
    {'x1': 2257, 'y1': 2787, 'x2': 2419, 'y2': 2787},
    {'x1': 2256, 'y1': 2788, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2788},
    {'x1': 2256, 'y1': 2789, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2789},
    {'x1': 2256, 'y1': 2790, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2790},
    {'x1': 2256, 'y1': 2791, 'x2': 2459, 'y2': 2798},
    {'x1': 2265, 'y1': 2791, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2791},
    {'x1': 2409, 'y1': 2792, 'x2': 2460, 'y2': 2796},
    {'x1': 2351, 'y1': 2792, 'x2': 2454, 'y2': 2794},
    {'x1': 2352, 'y1': 2794, 'x2': 2431, 'y2': 2794},
    {'x1': 2317, 'y1': 2795, 'x2': 2431, 'y2': 2798},
    {'x1': 2255, 'y1': 2795, 'x2': 2316, 'y2': 2795},
    {'x1': 2255, 'y1': 2796, 'x2': 2316, 'y2': 2797},
    {'x1': 2339, 'y1': 2797, 'x2': 2395, 'y2': 2798},

    ],
    [
    {'x1': 1892, 'y1': 125, 'x2': 2124, 'y2': 125}
    {'x1': 2127, 'y1': 126, 'x2': 2200, 'y2': 127},
    {'x1': 1981, 'y1': 126, 'x2': 2126, 'y2': 126},
    {'x1': 2004, 'y1': 127, 'x2': 2183, 'y2': 127},
    {'x1': 2116, 'y1': 128, 'x2': 2350, 'y2': 128},
    {'x1': 2439, 'y1': 129, 'x2': 2648, 'y2': 129},
    {'x1': 2285, 'y1': 130, 'x2': 2395, 'y2': 131},
    {'x1': 2339, 'y1': 130, 'x2': 2761, 'y2': 130},
    {'x1': 2396, 'y1': 131, 'x2': 2801, 'y2': 131},
    {'x1': 3003, 'y1': 132, 'x2': 3137, 'y2': 132},
    {'x1': 2567, 'y1': 132, 'x2': 2842, 'y2': 132},
    {'x1': 2969, 'y1': 133, 'x2': 3138, 'y2': 133},
    {'x1': 2607, 'y1': 133, 'x2': 2842, 'y2': 133},
    {'x1': 2915, 'y1': 134, 'x2': 3208, 'y2': 134}
    ]
]
```

Comment: How would you handle grouping sets of lines where `y1` values range from 1 to 20 (so the specified range of 10 for distance isn't clearly separated between potential groups)?

Comment: It is a good question, in my case the same as with other cases since I do some more processing after the grouping part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this might work for you:

Sort by the the `y1` value:

```
new_lines = sorted(horizontal_lines, key=lambda k: k['y1'])


[
    {"x1": 1892, "y1": 125, "x2": 2124, "y2": 125},
    {"x1": 2127, "y1": 126, "x2": 2200, "y2": 127},
    {"x1": 1981, "y1": 126, "x2": 2126, "y2": 126},
    {"x1": 2004, "y1": 127, "x2": 2183, "y2": 127},
    {"x1": 2116, "y1": 128, "x2": 2350, "y2": 128},
    {"x1": 2439, "y1": 129, "x2": 2648, "y2": 129},
    {"x1": 2285, "y1": 130, "x2": 2395, "y2": 131},
    {"x1": 2339, "y1": 130, "x2": 2761, "y2": 130},
    {"x1": 2396, "y1": 131, "x2": 2801, "y2": 131},
    {"x1": 3003, "y1": 132, "x2": 3137, "y2": 132},
    {"x1": 2567, "y1": 132, "x2": 2842, "y2": 132},
    {"x1": 2969, "y1": 133, "x2": 3138, "y2": 133},
    {"x1": 2607, "y1": 133, "x2": 2842, "y2": 133},
    {"x1": 2915, "y1": 134, "x2": 3208, "y2": 134},
    {"x1": 2257, "y1": 2787, "x2": 2419, "y2": 2787},
    {"x1": 2256, "y1": 2788, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2788},
    {"x1": 2256, "y1": 2789, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2789},
    {"x1": 2256, "y1": 2790, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2790},
    {"x1": 2256, "y1": 2791, "x2": 2459, "y2": 2798},
    {"x1": 2265, "y1": 2791, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2791},
    {"x1": 2409, "y1": 2792, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2796},
    {"x1": 2351, "y1": 2792, "x2": 2454, "y2": 2794},
    {"x1": 2352, "y1": 2794, "x2": 2431, "y2": 2794},
    {"x1": 2317, "y1": 2795, "x2": 2431, "y2": 2798},
    {"x1": 2255, "y1": 2795, "x2": 2316, "y2": 2795},
    {"x1": 2255, "y1": 2796, "x2": 2316, "y2": 2797},
    {"x1": 2339, "y1": 2797, "x2": 2395, "y2": 2798},
]
```

Then there are probably a few ways to split this up

```
def get_index(new_list, delta):
    indexs = [0]
    for i in range(len(new_list) - 1):
        if new_list[i]["y1"] + delta < new_list[i + 1]["y1"]:
            indexs.extend((i + 1, i + 1))
    indexs.append(len(new_list))
    it = iter(indexs)
    split_list = []
    for x in it:
        split_list.append(new_list[x : next(it)])
    return split_list
```

> get_index(new_lines, 10)

```
[
    [
        {"x1": 1892, "y1": 125, "x2": 2124, "y2": 125},
        {"x1": 2127, "y1": 126, "x2": 2200, "y2": 127},
        {"x1": 1981, "y1": 126, "x2": 2126, "y2": 126},
        {"x1": 2004, "y1": 127, "x2": 2183, "y2": 127},
        {"x1": 2116, "y1": 128, "x2": 2350, "y2": 128},
        {"x1": 2439, "y1": 129, "x2": 2648, "y2": 129},
        {"x1": 2285, "y1": 130, "x2": 2395, "y2": 131},
        {"x1": 2339, "y1": 130, "x2": 2761, "y2": 130},
        {"x1": 2396, "y1": 131, "x2": 2801, "y2": 131},
        {"x1": 3003, "y1": 132, "x2": 3137, "y2": 132},
        {"x1": 2567, "y1": 132, "x2": 2842, "y2": 132},
        {"x1": 2969, "y1": 133, "x2": 3138, "y2": 133},
        {"x1": 2607, "y1": 133, "x2": 2842, "y2": 133},
    ],
    [
        {"x1": 2257, "y1": 2787, "x2": 2419, "y2": 2787},
        {"x1": 2256, "y1": 2788, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2788},
        {"x1": 2256, "y1": 2789, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2789},
        {"x1": 2256, "y1": 2790, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2790},
        {"x1": 2256, "y1": 2791, "x2": 2459, "y2": 2798},
        {"x1": 2265, "y1": 2791, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2791},
        {"x1": 2409, "y1": 2792, "x2": 2460, "y2": 2796},
        {"x1": 2351, "y1": 2792, "x2": 2454, "y2": 2794},
        {"x1": 2352, "y1": 2794, "x2": 2431, "y2": 2794},
        {"x1": 2317, "y1": 2795, "x2": 2431, "y2": 2798},
        {"x1": 2255, "y1": 2795, "x2": 2316, "y2": 2795},
        {"x1": 2255, "y1": 2796, "x2": 2316, "y2": 2797},
        {"x1": 2339, "y1": 2797, "x2": 2395, "y2": 2798},
    ],
]
```

Comment: there seems to be a bug, sometimes the output does not include all the original lines. Consider this input:     [{'x1': 2915, 'y1': 135, 'x2': 3232, 'y2': 135},
    {'x1': 3122, 'y1': 136, 'x2': 3248, 'y2': 136},
    {'x1': 78, 'y1': 1377, 'x2': 206, 'y2': 1377},
    {'x1': 78, 'y1': 1378, 'x2': 274, 'y2': 1378}]

Comment: you are right, it is excluding the last item in every sub list except for the final one, just an indexing issue. Fixed